Object is possibly 'undefined' in vue3 typescript
The code below is based on vue3 with typescript used.
export interface TenantDto {
  uuid: string;
  name: string;
}

export const useTenantStore = defineStore('tenant', {
  state: () => ({
    tenants: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    setMyTenants: (payload: TenantDto[]) => {
      this.tenants = payload;
    },
  }
);

compiling the code in production produces a error on the line
this.tenants = payload;


The error is saying Object is possibly 'undefined'.

how would I get it around ?

You cannot use arrow function to define actions since it relies on the this keyword.
Try this instead:
export const useTenantStore = defineStore('tenant', {
  state: () => ({
    tenants: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    setMyTenants(payload: TenantDto[]) {
      this.tenants = payload;
    }
  }
});


However @alexwbt described the problem & solution, another alternative could be to specify Setup Stores instead of Option Stores.
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { ref } from 'vue';

export const useTenantStore = defineStore('tenant', () => {
  const tenants = ref([]);
  
  const setMyTenants = (payload) => {
    tenants.value = payload;
  }

  return {
    tenants,
    setMyTenants,
  };
});

